# How to add more EditText in xml layout at run time in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am making an android app which on pressing add button adds 2 TextViews at the bottom of other TextViews. I have made a layout on xml. Now the problem is how to point out that layout in java part and then adding TextViews at the run time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add TextView in Runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976668/how-to-add-textview-in-runtime)

Comment: I am not getting it. What is parent supposed to allocate? What is context?

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumed that you are using **LinearLayout** as a layout...!

Use this code in your activity,

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
tv.setText("test");
layout.addView(tv);
```

Comment: What if i have a relative layout?

Comment: Same kind of idea, but you'll need to explicitly position each added view relative to the view above.

Comment: Then simply replace LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and it will work...!

Comment: Okay Thanks. Let me try this